add_ci() in gtsummary placing confidence interval on wrong row when using continuous2 is used
I am creating a descriptive table using the gtsummary package. For each variable, I'd like to have a row for the variable label, and then sub-rows for each factor. I then present the confidence interval in a 95% CI in a new column.
The 95% CI works for categorical variables, where they are placed next to each factor. However, for continuous variables, they are placed at the row header.
The code below illustrates my issue:
mtcars %>%
  tbl_summary(
    type = all_continuous() ~ 'continuous2',
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                     all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
    digits = list(all_continuous() ~ c(1, 1)),
    missing = "no"
  ) %>%
  add_ci(
    include = everything(),
    statistic = list(all_continuous2() ~ "{conf.low} - {conf.high}", 
                     all_categorical() ~ "{conf.low}% - {conf.high}%"
                     ),
    conf.level = 0.95,
    pattern = NULL,
    ) %>%
  bold_labels()

Output below:

Ass you can see, the confidence interval for mpg is on the mpg row instead of the Mean (SD) row.
My desired output is to have the confidence interval for continuous variables to be next to the sub-rows.
Thoughts on how to resolve this?
Thanks so much!

I think what you meant to ask was,  "Can I change the default placement of the CI?" You can just modify the underlying data frame with the modify_table_body() function to migrate the stats to another row.

This was resolved following code from this post: enter link description here
My updated code is as follows, only for continuous variables:
  tbl_summary(
    include = mpg,
    type = all_continuous() ~ 'continuous2',
    statistic = list(all_continuous() ~ "{mean} ({sd})",
                     all_categorical() ~ "{n} ({p}%)"),
    digits = list(all_continuous() ~ c(1, 1)),
    missing = "no"
  ) %>%
  add_ci(
    include = mpg,
    statistic = list(all_continuous2() ~ "{conf.low} - {conf.high}", 
                     all_categorical() ~ "{conf.low}% - {conf.high}%"
                     ),
    conf.level = 0.95,
    pattern = NULL,
    ) %>%
  bold_labels()

for (x in paste0("ci_stat_", 0)) {
  summary_table$table_body[[x]] <- dplyr::lag(summary_table$table_body[[x]])
}

summary_table


